# How to use transform scale() to do the same thing as 'zoom'?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I was working on zooming-in the web page using 'zoom', I was told that it's not standard css so I shouldn't use it in our project. Then I switched to use the standard 'transform: scale()' with 'transform-origin: top center', but there is one problem: I always want to zoom-in the page to be 150%, it works for large dimension devices, but for some small dimension devices, the page gets out of the bounding. Using 'zoom' won't cause such issue since it can auto adjust the layout. I wonder how I can achieve similar effects by using 'transform'?

Thanks.

Comment: why not use @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {}

Comment: Would you please share your code?

Comment: @Masud my css code was just:
`body {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transform-origin:top center;
}`

Comment: @StefanAvramovic so as for my css `body {   transform: scale(1.5);   transform-origin:top center; }`, shall I add it into the `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {<HERE>}` ?

Comment: maybe you only want to increase/decrease font-size and not rescale the whole layout, is it ? Also, do you use : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` ? why not zoom : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @media to set the rule of when the css should be applied

```
//this will only run if screen less than 600px
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
body {   transform: scale(1);   transform-origin:top center; }


}
//this will only run if screen larger than 600px 
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
body {   transform: scale(1.5);   transform-origin:top center; }


}
```

Comment: I think this solved my problem! Thank you! One more q: how can I get the current screen width?

Comment: If you mean with javascript then it is var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;